# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements when the XPath expression is null error displaying while sending keys through Method

Tags: selenium

Getting error while Sendkeys through methods.

```
public static void enterTask(String task) throws Exception  {
    // Entering task name
    GUIFunctions.typeTxtboxValue(driver,By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("enterTaskName_XPATH")),task);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

But while send keys directly it is working fine.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("enterTaskName_xpath"))).sendKeys("qaz");
```

Comment: issued with Caps in xpath

Answer (score 0):

You have used incorrect key in ObjRepoProp.getProperty() method. See below:

```
    GUIFunctions.typeTxtboxValue(driver,By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("enterTaskName_XPATH")),task);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("enterTaskName_xpath"))).sendKeys("qaz");
```

The key "enterTaskName_xpath" is used as "enterTaskName_XPATH". Below code should work:

```
    GUIFunctions.typeTxtboxValue(driver,By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("enterTaskName_xpath")),task);
```

Comment: Did this solution work for you? I am facing the same issue and i tried removing caps from my xpath but it didnt work for me. Any idea, what is the problem?